# Mongo shell .save() triggers success callback but document not in database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am calling the .save() method on a Mongo document. The success callback is triggered and I am passed the saved document, but the table in my database still has zero documents in it. `db.estimates.count()` when I am using the uberEstimator database returns 0.

I've closely modeled this code off other working code I have, and I just can't figure out where I've gone wrong. Am I not using `.save()` correctly?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
if (process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/uberEstimator')
}

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => console.log('mongoose connection open!'));

var estimateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  rideTier: String,
   ...
});

var Estimate = mongoose.model('Estimate', estimateSchema);

const save = ({display_name, distance, high_estimate, low_estimate, duration, estimate, currency_code, 
start_latitude, start_longitude, end_latitude, end_longitude, start_address, end_address}) => {
  let props = {
    rideTier: display_name,
    ...
  }
  var estimate = new Estimate(props);
  console.log(estimate);
  estimate.save((err, newEstimate) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('saved new estimate to db');
    console.log(newEstimate);
  })
};

var sample = JSON.parse('{"localized_display_name": "uberX","distance": 6.17,"display_name": "uberX","product_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d","high_estimate": 17,"low_estimate": 13,"duration": 1080,"estimate": "$13-17","currency_code": "USD"}')
sample.start_address = '300 Albany St';
save(sample);
```

I get these logs:

```
mongoose connection open!
saved new estimate to db
{ _id: 5bca37267a478b31718445f3,
  rideTier: 'uberX',
  distance: 6.17,
  highEstimate: 17,
  lowEstimate: 13,
  duration: 1080,
  estimateString: '$13-17',
  currency: 'USD',
  start_address: '300 Albany St',
  __v: 0 }
```

But still get the following when examining the table via Mongo shell:

```
> use uberEstimator
switched to db uberEstimator
> show tables
estimates
> use estimates
switched to db estimates
> db.estimates.count()
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `use estimates` switches current database to `estimates` and I guess that's not what you want to achieve here. Based on your code it seems like you want to browse `uberEstimator` **database** and `estimates` **collection** so you can simply try:

```
use uberEstimator
db.estimates.count()
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you!